# Read *.data file into dynamically expanding array of struct***

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, structure, readfile

I am newbie to C programming and I am suppose to read *.data file into dynamically expanding array of structures. Once completed I am suppose to Sort by Value and Print in High/Low order. I have been able to accomplish Sort & Print function but not the READING of the file.
I have gone through couple of examples but unable to understand. Any help would  be appreciated. Thanks

Sample Data in File

### alpha 4.8 28000 white

### delta 1.2 321 orange

```
struct dataBase
{
    char modelName[31];
    float capacity;
    int mileage;
    char color[15];
};

int main (void)
{

readData();

// set up conditions for the loop

int choice;
choice = 0;

// I used a do while loop to insure that it would run once
do{
    // print menu
    printf ( "Make your choice.\n");
    printf ( "1. Sort data by the float value & print high to low.\n" );
    printf ( "2. Sort data by the float value & print low to high.\n" );
    printf ( "3. Sort data by the int value & print high to low.\n" );
    printf ( "4. Sort data by the int value & print low to high.\n");
    printf ( "5. Exit.\n\n");

    // get user input and clear out stdin
    choice = getchar();
    // this part clears the stdin of leftovers
    while ( getchar() != '\n' ) ;

    // Call the desired function
    if (choice == '1' ) {
        compareFloat();
        printHigh(Input_Size);
    }
    else if (choice == '2' ) {
        compareFloat();
        printLow(Input_Size);
    }
    else if (choice == '3' ) {
        compareInt();
        printHigh(Input_Size);
    }
    else if (choice == '4') {
        compareInt(Input_Size);
    }
}
// Check for escape code
while ( choice != '5');

// just to verify I finished
printf ( "Done\n");

return 0;         
}

int compareFloat(const void *s1, const void *s2)
{
  struct dataBase *e1 = (struct dataBase *)s1;
  struct dataBase *e2 = (struct dataBase *)s2;
  if (e1->capacity < e2->capacity)
    return -1;
  else if (e1->capacity > e2->capacity)
    return +1;
  else
    return 0;
}

void printLow(int size)
{
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        printf(dataBase[i].modelName + " " + dataBase[i].capacity + " " + 
               dataBase[i].mileage + " " + dataBase[i].color);
    }
}

void readData(void)
{
    FILE *inputFile
    inputFile = fopen("file.data", 'rb');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

struct dataBase
{
    char modelName[31];
    float capacity;
    int mileage;
    char color[15];
};

struct dataBase *Inputs      = NULL;
size_t           Inputs_Size = 0;
size_t           Num_Inputs  = 0;

void printLow(int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        printf("%s %f %d %s\n", Inputs[i].modelName, Inputs[i].capacity, Inputs[i].mileage, Inputs[i].color);
    }
}

void readData(void)
{
    FILE *inputFile;
    struct dataBase input;

    if (NULL == (inputFile = fopen("file.data", "r")))
    {
        perror("Couldn't open file.data!");
        return;
    }

    while (4 == fscanf(inputFile, "%30s %f %d %14s", input.modelName, &input.capacity, &input.mileage, input.color))
    {
        if (++Num_Inputs > Inputs_Size)
        {
            size_t new_size = 2 * Num_Inputs;
            struct dataBase *new_inputs = realloc(Inputs, new_size * sizeof(struct dataBase));

            if (NULL == new_inputs)
            {
                perror("realloc failed!");
                goto FAIL_INPUTFILE;
            }

            Inputs      = new_inputs;
            Inputs_Size = new_size;
       }

       Inputs[Num_Inputs - 1] = input;
       printf("'%s' %f %d '%s'\n", input.modelName, input.capacity, input.mileage, input.color);
    }

    if (!feof(inputFile))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Malformed line didn't match expected input format!\n");
    }

FAIL_INPUTFILE:    
    fclose(inputFile);
}

int main()
{
  readData();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: But how will the structure expand dynamically? And How would I add entry into the collection?

Comment: Ah, I thought your problem was just with the I/O.  Give me a sec to update my answer.

Comment: this code works perfectly for my I/O. Would it be also possible for you to review my other codes and will they work as intended?

Comment: Your capacity comparison fcn looks good.  Your printLow does not.  C doesn't concatenate strings using the + operator like Java does.  I'll update my answer for that too.

Comment: I see. And then do I call my functions appropriately in the main().

Comment: You don't want to call your comparison function, which only compares two entries.  You need to call a sorting function that will use your comparison function to sort the Inputs.  Google the function qsort(), which is part of the standard library and declared in stdlib.h  Feed that your comparator function and the array properly and it will sort it for you.  If you need to write your own sort function, then that's a lot more work you need to figure out. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71064/discussion-between-user3337714-and-jschultz410).